# How to ensure consistent display of fonts?

Tags: browser, unicode, fonts, cross-browser, quasar-framework

I built an SPA that displays at some point in a `<div>`

```
vider ️
```

(️ is copied from [Emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/fork-and-knife-with-plate/) or [Unicode Character Table](https://unicode-table.com/en/1F37D/)).

On my Windows 10 with Chrome, this is displayed as

[image]

When running the same `dist` content on a Raspberry Pi with [luakit](https://luakit.github.io/) , I see

[image]

The emoji is gone.

Is there a way to ensure it is present in every display - or at least how to **make it display on that other device/browser**? My understanding is that the fonts are provided in `dist/spa/fonts` so they should be available to the browser (?)

EDIT: the `font-family` is set by the framework and is

```
font-family: "Roboto", "-apple-system", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

It is [embedded](https://quasar.dev/style/typography#default-font) in the SPA

Comment: What CSS are you using to style the text? It seems that different browsers are selecting different fonts, so the CSS `font-family` declaration would help determine the issue.

Comment: @Smitop: good point, thanks; I updated the question with info about `font-family`

Answer (score 1):

None of the fonts in that font stack have emoji glpyhs in them. As such, the browser looks for emoji fonts on the system and tries to use them to render the emojis. If the system doesn't have any applicable fonts, then the browser is unable to render emojis. You can remedy this by adding an emoji font to your font stack, such as [Noto Emoji](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/blob/main/fonts/NotoColorEmoji.ttf). Add it to your font stack like so:

```css
font-family: "Roboto", "-apple-system", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Noto Emoji", sans-serif;
```

Font lookup is done on a per-character basis, so browsers will look for the emoji in each font on the list, until they try `Noto Emoji` and find it there.

But keep in mind that emoji fonts tend to be big. The color version of Noto emoji is ~9 MiB. If you only display a few emoji, you should probably just convert them to an image and render the image instead. This is what Twitter does: it converts all emojis in Tweets to images, ensuring that only the emojis needed to render the Tweet get downloaded.

Comment: *the browser looks for emoji fonts on the system and tries to use them to render the emojis* thanks for the very complete answer - I was not aware that the browser would try other fonts than the ones in the stack, this is why there is a difference between Windows and Raspban. I will test this today as soon as I ma home.

Answer (score 0):

Before to the right answer, you should consider what do you mean for *consistent*. Users usually care about consistent on they device, and not about a website which is consistent on different browser (in fact, users will use just a browser, so they do not care about this type of consistency, so if you are building something for users, take this into account).

Every operating system and browsers uses different fonts (which may depend also on version and language). So you cannot have consistent look using system fonts.

If you want to take control on visualization, you should use webfonts (and really, you should use web-fonts if you are using non basic characters). In practice either you download and serve a font, or you link to a wellknow web font provider (Google had many of them for free, check https://fonts.google.com/, it gives you also the code to include on your CSS). In such case, you tell browser exactly what font (and version) to use, and you give the use also the font. So you have full control. Webfonts are also a frequently used features so it is supported by all modern browsers)

In MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Web_fonts) you find the information about how to use webfonts.

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

A special character will not necessarily be on a client's machine unless you put it there. An emoji like that is not by default going to be everywhere you'd hope.

### Longer Answer

Either using the @import command in your CSS file, or a `<link rel...` in the `<head>` you can import the needed font(s) with the special characters or symbols. You don't even need to host them in your pi. For a big symbols font though, it can be a big file, BUT...

If a font on google fonts does have the needed symbol, Google fonts API has a means to access and download *only the specific glyph*, by indicating in the parameter string of the URL with a `&text=ABC` in this case, only the uppercase letters **A B C** are downloaded.

However, for anything other than alphanumeric, you need to escape them for the URL, for insteance to download only the trademark and copyright ™ © symbols: `&text=%E2%84%A2%C2%A9`

For you, Google fonts has a symbols version of Noto, and you can download only the dinner plate using the escaped value of `%F0%9F%8D%BD` here's the import you'd need for your CSS sheet:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+Symbols+2&text=%F0%9F%8D%BD&display=swap');
```

The @import command adds the Google supplied CSS @font-face. Then in your font fallback list, put it behind your main font(s), ideally far enough down the list that it only gets called when you specifically need it:

```css
* {
  font-family: "Roboto", "Apple Color Emoji", 'Noto Sans Symbols 2', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Here, the browser will try and fill with Roboto and apple-system first, so if "Apple Color Emoji" has the symbol, then the noto version won't be grabbed... but will for anyone that does not have "Apple Color Emoji" on their machine.

In this way you could add fonts that a user might likely have locally to your fallback list.

On the other hand, if it's just one or two like this, you might want to reduce it to a png or svg and use that directly instead.